# How to view Terminal keybindings in macOS?

Tags: terminal, mojave

How can I view a complete list of keybindings in macOS for the Terminal app?

E.g. <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a new Terminal tab.

I can only find incomplete tutorials on the web, but I'd like to know where to find this information on the system itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see which key combinations are supported in Terminal, look through the menus or open the help page from the help menu.

A utility I find quite useful is [CheatSheet](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/) which lists all key combinations currently available if you press and hold <kbd>Command</kbd> key for a few seconds.